# Android AXML text not showing on button

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to make a button that has three elements: Text, arrow icon, and a background color. I have done what I believe is the right way to do it. It looks fine in the designer view but text does not appear in the emulator. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

The emulator I am using is "Nougat" (Android 7.1 - API 25).

[image: Button in design view]

[image: Button in emulator view]

Here's the axml for the button:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Medications"
        local:MvxBind="Text Medications"
        android:id="@+id/Medications"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/Arrow4"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: At a glance the XML looks ok...any chance you're setting a text programmatically and unintentionally setting it to a an empty/null string?

Comment: Now that you say that..  I see that someone added the "local:MvxBind" property to my button.  I bet that's the cause.  Thanks for pointing that out!